# Replace filter not working properly after upgrade to logstash 7.1.1

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to replace the timestamp parsed from my message with existing timestamp + year (parsed from the source of the file).

This below code was working perfectly in ***logstash*** ***6.7.2*** but after upgrading to ***7.1.1*** its not working anymore.

**source = /syslog-data/DC1/NETWORK-DEVICES/UDP/IP/2018/09/IP-2018-09-17.log**

```
grok {
match => { "source" => "/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{YEAR:year}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}"}
}

mutate {
replace => [ "[system][netlog][timestamp]", "%{[system][netlog][timestamp]} %{year}" ]
}

date {
match => [
"[system][netlog][timestamp]",
"MMM d HH:mm:ss YYYY",
"MMM dd HH:mm:ss YYYY"
]
target => "@timestamp"
}

mutate {
remove_field => ["year"]
}
```

After this the value of `[system][netlog][timestamp]` becomes `Sep 17 00:00:02 %{year}`, but previously it was giving the output `Sep 17 00:00:02 2018`

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: In grok, I think there is no field with "[system][netlog][timestamp]" all the values are going in GREEDYDATA except year. Please check grok pattern once

Comment: "[system][netlog][timestamp]" this one is parsed from previous grok which is not given here. The problem is whatever i use in place of %{year it just print that. But it should put the output of that string there.

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me

```
grok {
match => { "message" => "/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{YEAR:year}/%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA}-(?<system_log_timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY})"}
  }
   mutate {
    copy => {
        "[system_log_timestamp]" => "[system][netlog][timestamp]"
    }
  }
mutate {
replace => [ "[system][netlog][timestamp]", "%{[system][netlog][timestamp]} %{year}" ]
}

date {
match => [
"[system][netlog][timestamp]",
"MMM dd HH:mm:ss YYYY"
]
target => "@timestamp"
}

mutate {
remove_field => ["year"]
}
```

Try with this, i took timestamp in grok only

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. After a bit of tweaking here and there i found that after replacing the double quotation with single quotation solved the problem. I don't know know why!! But hey its works. :P